# Strange network traffic on my dedicated server. How to find out what is causing it

Tags: networking, linux, linux-networking, network-monitoring

I noticed a trange outgoing traffic in my dedicated server. I'd like to know how could I find out what is the reason to this.

[image: One day traffic]
**One day traffic**
[image: One week traffic]

**One week traffic**

As you can see, there are bursts of spikes to over 20 megs of outgoing traffic.
There is always a lower of outgoing data, before the burst.

Is there any command I could use to know with application is causing this?

Sorry I couldn't express using the best form.

Comment: How is this strange traffic? Looks quite normal to me.

Comment: not its not normal. It wasnt like that some time ago.

Answer (score 3):

That looks pretty normal to me.  Perhaps you can show us the graphs where it was looking different?  Your bandwidth levels are never going to form a perfect line in the graph.  If your server was compromised, I'd expect to be seeing a large amount of bandwidth being used all the time.

How is this data being collected?  Is it via SNMP?  If you're getting this data through something that only supports 32bit counters, the noise  you are seeing could just be the counters overflowing, and your graphing software not handling it correctly.  Upgrading to something that supports 64bit counters might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> **NETHOGS**

It provides process specific network usage.

After that you can use jnettop of Iftop to monitor that which type of connections are making huge amount of traffic on network.

For Detailed analysis of network trqffic with Graphing and realtime update, with historical data representation, you can use two utilities:

> NTOP
>
> IPAUDIT

Answer (score 0):

`iftop` is a nice tool to watch online your top talkers. Perhaps that will give you an idea.